# Poner Contraseña a documento mediante post (php)

Tags: php

Forma de hacer funcionar este código php para poner contraseña.

```
$password = $_POST['clave'];
if ($password !== 12345 ){
echo"
<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">
<input type=\"password\" name=\"clave\">
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar\">
</form>";
}else{
echo"Clave correcta ";
}
```

Meda error

> Notice: Undefined index: clave

Y no funciona Espero su ayuda Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al principio tu indice no existe y marca error, has lo siguiente

```
$password = isset($_POST['clave']) ? $_POST['clave'] : '';
```

Básicamente lo que se hace ahí es preguntar si existe el inidice "clave en el arreglo", si no existe, se asigna uno por default a la variable password, en este caso un vacio

PD. si usas php7 en adelante puedes hacer esto

```
 $password = $_POST['clave'] ?? '';
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato ya no tira el error **Notice: Undefined index: clave** pero aun no logro hacer funcionar la contraseña en la pagina por mas que pongo 12345 no sale **Clave correcta** tienes alguna idea de como tiene que ponerse el código

Answer (score 3):

El error se produce debido a que estás comparando una cadena alfanumérica con un número.
En los arrays tipo $_POST ($_GET, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE, etc.), el tipo de dato siempre es string salvo que se indique de otra manera.
por lo tanto, el contenido de tu $_POST['clave'] será '12345' y tú estás comparándolo con 12345 que es numérico.

Para hacer correctamente la comparación deberías usar esto

```
if ($password !== '12345' ){
```

SALU2
de Navegante

Comment: Excelente aporte, solo para complementar si usara un != en vez de !== también funcionaría ya que no compararía que fueran del mismo tipo

Comment: Efectivamente sin la doble igualdad también funcionaría. En ese caso no se realizaría la validación del tipo de dato, pero precisamente por eso lo incluí ya que el problema inicial radicaba en que el tipo de dato era incompatible. Con esa validación "extra" conseguimos que PHP nos "cante" el error exactamente.